# Python logging configuration file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I seem to be having some issues while attempting to implement logging into my python project.

I'm simply attempting to mimic the following configuration:

[Python Logging to Multiple Destinations](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations)

However instead of doing this inside of code, I'd like to have it in a configuration file.

Below is my config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=('logs/testSuite.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=INFO
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

The problem is that my screen output looks like:
      2010-12-14 11:39:04,066 - root - WARNING - 3
      2010-12-14 11:39:04,066 - root - ERROR - 4
      2010-12-14 11:39:04,066 - root - CRITICAL - 5

My file is output, but looks the same as above (although with the extra information included).  However the debug and info levels are not output to either.

I am on Python 2.7

Here is my simple example showing failure:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import logging.config

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath("shared/"))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath("tests/"))

class Main(object):

  @staticmethod
  def main():
    logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
    logging.debug("1")
    logging.info("2")
    logging.warn("3")
    logging.error("4")
    logging.critical("5")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Main.main()
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like you've set the levels for your handlers, but not your logger. The logger's level filters every message before it can reach its handlers and the default is `WARNING` and above (as you can see). Setting the root logger's level to `NOTSET` as you have, as well as setting it to `DEBUG` (or whatever is the lowest level you wish to log) should solve your issue.

Answer (score 16):

Adding the following line to the root logger took care of my problem:

```
level=NOTSET
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add log level in `[logger_root]`. It is worked.

```
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen,file
```

Comment: I am facing same issues.

Comment: But, i added log level under [logger_root] and it is work well.

Comment: Just add log level under logger_root @Scott

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach to both write to terminal and file would be as following:

```
import logging.config

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("log_file.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
logger.info('message')
logger.error('message')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.config import dictConfig

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
}
def configure_logging(logfile_path):
    """
    Initialize logging defaults for Project.

    :param logfile_path: logfile used to the logfile
    :type logfile_path: string

    This function does:

    - Assign INFO and DEBUG level to logger file handler and console handler

    """
    dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

    default_formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] [%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s] [PID:%(process)d TID:%(thread)d] %(message)s",
        "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile_path, maxBytes=10485760,backupCount=300, encoding='utf-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)
    console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

    logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.root.addHandler(file_handler)
    logging.root.addHandler(console_handler)



[31/10/2015 22:00:33] [DEBUG] [yourmodulename] [yourfunction_name():9] [PID:61314 TID:140735248744448] this is logger infomation from hello module
```

I think you should add the disable_existing_loggers to false.