# How to avoid the impact of verbose logging?

Tags: python, logging

How can one buffer verbose logging statements (i.e. `logging.debug("...")`) until the end of a python process? 
Would this require a custom logger?

My current setup uses a config file similar to [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441842/python-logging-configuration-file)

(Windows Python2.7)

Comment: If you want to buffer all of the debug logging, you would need some sort of custom implementation.

Comment: Buffering causes other problems if you have a lot of logging, so why not just redirect to a file?

Comment: unfortunately, my logging has to occur after I write to a [lab streaming layer](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer) network.. logging to a file interferes with this communication. timing out for just under a half second avoids this problem, but isn't desireable in time sensitive applications